# how do i cut features in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to cut just the pages system and the appearance-> editor 
from the wordpress wp-admin.

because i don't want all these features because writing a pages system and template editor is a time consuming.

because wordpress is open source project and i just need those for my applications 
i searched a lot and found that even wp-admin folder is hard to change because it's hard coded so what's the simplest way to cut those features.

i just want this http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages
and this 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen

Comment: Ever tried using punctuation in sentences?

Comment: There are a couple of apostrophes in there ... oh, and a period ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all those menu items easily:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Stripping the actual code and dismantling Wordpress features entirely is a whole other story. But probably not wise if you ever plan on updating WP base.

Comment: You're welcome. This of course just hides those menu items. You could consider access control for certain items, or just locking down certain files with .htaccess rules or something along those lines. The Wordpress Admin Menu Editor plugin has more options. Also this article has some other ideas for further branding your admin: http://www.nikibrown.com/designoblog/2011/07/24/customizing-wordpress-admin-for-clients/